# Possible to use geofencing (region monitoring) on iOS without "Always" location access?

Tags: core-location, geofencing

I wrote some test code that alerts me in the background when I've left a region or entered it. Works great with "Always" location access. — However, if I change the app's location access to "When In Use", it doesn't work anymore. Works again when reverted.

I was under the impression (as were others) that geofencing (region monitoring) on iOS should work **without** "Always" location access. Is there an entitlement or setting somewhere to enable it to work correctly?

The hollow arrow doesn't even appear in the status bar without "Always", which is kind of a tip-off that it's not supported without "Always" being turned on, but yeah....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected. Region monitoring, visit monitoring, significant Location Changes are handled on the OS level and to work need Always access. This is a screen shot from [WWDC Core Location Best Practice Minute 14:09](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/716/?time=848)

[image]

Comment: What is "Background Location Session" ...?

Comment: Not sure. I'm guessing that means location working in backgroud. Standard would mean it working in foreground. I would have to go through the WWDC. You could also read/search its transcript

Comment: @BenGuild It seems that I was right. From this [moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/716/?time=196): The first one we are going to talk about is the bread and butter of Core Location, the standard location service. It comes in two different versions. The first version is the single location API.
When you call Request Location, Core Location will do its best to produce an estimate of the user's position, and then deliver that to your delegate.
We also offer the continuous location API.

Comment: When you call Start Updating Location, Core Location will produce a stream of location updates, and deliver them all to your delegate. Remember to stop your location updates when you're done, since otherwise Core Location will continue to compute locations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and research/confirmation on this. I'm behind on my WWDC video watching this year :D

Comment: This is 2016...I haven't watched 2017 yet.

Comment: Yeah, but I just watched video 713 on 2017 because of you haha.