# Apple Geofencing failure When location services set "only while using the app"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, geofencing

Apple Geofencing is not working when the user sets "only while using the app" from Location permissions dialog. When they choose "Always" the apps geofencing services work fine. i use geofences to monitor when a user enters an alert zone and it does not work when the user selects "While Using App" from the location services permission dialog

My Question is :  Does an application with geofencing capabilities need location permissions set to "Always" from the user in order for geofencing to work properly? We are not using iBeacons

Regards
nivrit

Comment: Yes, it does need “always” permissions. If the user grants only in-use permissions then geofencing won’t work in the background. An appropriate approach is to check the permissions that have been granted and display a notice to the user regarding reduced functionality if only in-use permissions have been granted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to use geofencing (region monitoring) on iOS without "Always" location access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764047/possible-to-use-geofencing-region-monitoring-on-ios-without-always-location)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently for any region based location services you need always authorization: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization

> Apps cannot use any services that automatically relaunch the app, such as region monitoring or the significant location change service.

Answer (score 1):

Apps with geofencing capabilities need Always authorization, due to the need to monitor geofences even when the app isn’t running  .